# Not able to find the element in an iframe even when used switchto frame in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I have a web page which has email, password and login button in it.

My object it to first wait for the page to load then check if the element (email field) is visible. Then insert data in it and proceed.

When I have checked with `firepath` and console I found that web page has an `iframe` and those fields are inside the frame.

so I used the below code:

```
getWrappedDriver().switchTo().frame(0);
getWrappedDriver().waitForElementClickable(String locator);
```

But this did not help, though the element does appears on the web page when I run the code, still my webdriver is not able to find that element

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Show HTML or share link

Comment: you should attached HTML or share page link!

Comment: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/signin   is the link of the web page.

Comment: Required elements are not in iframe.

Comment: No They are in the frame only, else my webdriver would have been able to find the element.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in one of your comments, on the url `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/signin` it seems all of the `WebElements` i.e.  `email`, `password` and `login_button` are on the `Top Window`. Hence you do not need to switch to any `frame`. Here is the working code block:

```
package demo;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Q46139002_login 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        driver.get("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/signin");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).sendKeys("email_id");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='btnLogin']")).click();
    }
}
```